# how to set contentScaleFactor iOS

Tags: ios, glkview

Following is not working.

```
    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.contentScaleFactor=1.0;
```

logging the `view` and `[UIScreen mainScreen]` objects:

```
<GLKView: 0x15638f60; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CAEAGLLayer: 0x15638960>>
<UIScreen: 0x15629a60; bounds = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x15629c40; size = 640.000000 x 1136.000000>>
```

and `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];` is still 2.0 not 1.0

Do i need to set scale factor on some other object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UIScreen mainScreen].scale is the **actual scale of the physical device** the user is using.

(It is always "2.0" unless you have incredibly old machines. "3.0" machines are coming soon from Apple, 2014 apparently.)

Here's a typical example...

```
    float isf = 1.0 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    CGPatternRef strokePattern = CGPatternCreate(
                    NULL,
                    CGRectMake(0,0,wholeWidth,wholeHeight),

                    CGAffineTransformScale(
                        CGAffineTransformIdentity,
                        isf,-isf),

                    wholeWidth,wholeHeight,
                    kCGPatternTilingNoDistortion,
                    true,
                    &kPatternCallbacks);
```

hope it helps in some way!

Comment: My problem was poor understanding of the scaling. I thought 2.0 means 1/4 point/pixel when its actually 1/1 and 1.0 is 1/4.

Comment: Ill accept your answer since it is the only one :D i usually just delete questions with no replies which is why i have so few :D